# Installation problem regarding wifiphisher

Tags: software-installation, python

Can anyone tell me how to install wifiphisher on ubuntu 14.04?

When i clone the code from github an then on typing `cd wifiphisher` in terminal and then typing `ls -l` in terminal i am not able to find the file `wifiphisher.py` which is necessary for installation

Answer (score 2):

It always makes sense to check out the README.md of GitHub projects - in this particular case it contains more or less clear instructions.

Please give it a try and report back.

- Download the master from [here](https://github.com/sophron/wifiphisher)
- Extract the zip and navigate to the contained folder
- Follow the install instructions, which means run: `python setup.py install`.

If that worked without issues ....

- Run the tool by typing `wifiphisher` afterwards.

Comment: Got it working? If so - please mark the answer as 'working' for others which might come with a similar issue.